# CouchDB Referential Integrity

Tags: couchdb, referential-integrity, nosql

I am new to `CouchDB` and the `NoSQL` scene and coming from a `SQL` background. I have some questions on referential integrity, for example I have a product document as below

```
{
  type: "product"
  name: "Sweet Necklace"
  category: "necklace"
}
```

And each category have their own document

```
{
  type: "category",
  name: "necklace",
  custom_attr: ".."
}
```

Just for the sake of the argument, what happens when the stakeholder chose to rename the category from "necklace" to "accessories", what should happen on the products that have the category field set as "necklace"? Do I do a bulk update on all products with category equal to necklace? (I don't think `CouchDB` allows us to perform a "UPDATE ALL WHERE" kinda statement)

**What is the best practice on handling such situation?**

**P/S:** I chose to save the category name in the product document instead of a category ID since `NoSQL` encourages denormalization anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If you're maintaining a separate document for the category then you've not denormalized your data at all. In fact, by doing what you're doing, you're getting the worst of both worlds - no normalization and no denormalization.

Try something like this:

Product document:

```
{
  _id:"product:first_product",
  name:"First Product"
  category:"category:category_1"
}
```

Category document:

```
{
  _id:"category:category_1",
  name:"Category 1",
  custom_attr: {}
}
```

This way, when you change the name of the category, you're still referring to the correct document from all the product documents that have this category.

Note: you can still have a `type` field and let the `_id` remain as it is currently.

**Edit:**

To get the product/category info, you can define a map function like so:

```
function(doc){
  if(doc.id.indexOf('product:') === 0){
    // or if(doc.type === 'product') if you use the type field

    emit(doc, {'_id': doc.category});

  }
}
```

Now whenever you use this view and you set `include_docs` to true, the category information will be included in your results.

Comment: Following your example whenever I need the category name of the product I still need to query the Category collection isn't it? I thought this beats one of the purpose of NoSQL which is to eliminates joins.

Comment: No, you don't have to execute another request. I've updated the answer with an example.